# Java: Getting a substring from a String after special character

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string:

`/abc/def/ghfj/ijk/lmn.doc`

I would like to extract **ghfj** from  this.

I tried in this manner: `str.substring(str.indexOf("/",9),str.indexOf("/"));`

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: you can split the string on `/` and then get the 2nd value from the array.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not free-code-writing-service. We exchange our effort for your effort, so please show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far and explain problems you are facing?

Comment: Also you shouldn't probably use String methods here. Java has classes which can handle manipulating paths quite nicely like `File` on `Path`.

Comment: i tried in this manner: str.substring(str.indexOf("/",8),str.indexOf("/"));

Comment: Don't post code as comment (it can't be properly formatted there which makes it hard to read). Its place is in your question so use [edit] option and add it to your post.

Comment: Your updated example `/abc/def/ghfj/ijk/lmn.doc` doesn't really match with your code attempt since `str.indexOf("/",8)` is way after `def` (unless you don't want to select `def` here). Please update your question and include logic which which tells which element you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to find parent location of specified file simplest way would be using `File` class or `Path` instead of String methods. Your code will be more readable and probably safer.

Using `java.io.File`:

```
String location = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";

File f = new File(location);
String parentName = f.getParentFile().getName();

System.out.println(parentName);
```

Using `java.nio.file.Path`:

```
String location = "/abc/def/ghfj.doc";

Path p = Paths.get(location);
String parent = p.getParent().getFileName().toString();

System.out.println(parent);
```

Output in both cases: `def`

---

In case of selecting `def` in `/abc/def/ghfj/ijk/lmn.doc` you could use `Path#getName(N)` where `N` is zero-based index of elements from farthermost ancestor to selected file like `abc` is `0`, `def` is `1`,...

So your code can look like:

```
String location = "/abc/def/ghfj/ijk/lmn.doc";

Path p = Paths.get(location);
String parent = p.getName(1).getFileName().toString();

System.out.println(parent);// Output: def
```

Comment: But in my case i need to use only string methods i.e., i am struggling

Comment: "i need to use only string methods" can I know why? Is this some kind of homework task?

Comment: Yes,this is my homework task.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution using a regular expression and groups:

```
public class AClass {

    private static final String TEXT = "/abc/def/ghfj/ijk/lmn.doc";
    private static final String REGULAR_EXPRESSION = "(/[^/]*){2}/([^/]*)/.*";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGULAR_EXPRESSION);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(TEXT);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            // the following variable holds "ghfj"
            String value = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to be more precise in order to allow us to fine tune the regular expression to your concrete needs.

Edit: I edited the solution according to your own edit. The regular expression has to be understood as follows:

- `(/[^/]*){2}` : two times the character `/` followed by any character except `/`
- `/` : an additional `/`character
- `([^/]*)` : a group of characters not containing `/`
- `/.*` : a `/` character followed by any other character

Then `matcher.group(2)` returns the String held by the group represented by the `([^/]*)` part of the above regular expression.

Comment: without using split and pattern methods,can't we do this?

Comment: You're asking how to extract a substring from a String based on a specific condition. That's what regular expressions are for (even if your teacher asks you to find a non robust solution that uses substrings)

Comment: Yes my teacher asked to do this by using only string methods